# k3d failed to pull image "docker.io/rancher/pause:3.1"

Tags: docker, kubernetes, k3s

I've started k3d with `k3d create && k3d start`.

All pods fail to start with the following error:

> Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  14s (x2 over 31s)  kubelet,
>   k3d-k3s-default-server  Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code
>   = Unknown desc = failed to get sandbox image "docker.io/rancher/pause:3.1": failed to pull image
>   "docker.io/rancher/pause:3.1": failed to pull and unpack image
>   "docker.io/rancher/pause:3.1": failed to resolve reference
>   "docker.io/rancher/pause:3.1": failed to do request: Head
>   https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/rancher/pause/manifests/3.1: dial tcp:
>   lookup registry-1.docker.io: Try again

As [recommended by a k3d contributor](https://github.com/rancher/k3d/issues/144#issuecomment-552770960), I've exec'ed into the k3d server container and attempted to pull the image manually:

```
$ docker exec -it k3d-k3s-default-server sh
/ # ctr image pull docker.io/rancher/pause:3.1
docker.io/rancher/pause:3.1: resolving      |--------------------------------------|
elapsed: 4.9 s               total:   0.0 B (0.0 B/s)
ctr: failed to resolve reference "docker.io/rancher/pause:3.1": failed to do request: Head https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/rancher/pause/manifests/3.1: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io: Try again
```

In the host environment, `docker pull docker.io/rancher/pause:3.1` works just fine.

I've seen a number of people resolve the issue by tweaking various DNS settings. But none described how they arrived at their particular solution.

Solving this issue would make me happy. Discovering a general diagnosis strategy would make me even happier.

### What hasn't worked

From [here](https://github.com/rancher/k3d/issues/144#issuecomment-552863119):

> I got the issue. I had one entry in
>   /etc/systemd/network/en0.networking Deleted that file, and everything
>   is fine.

I have no files in `/etc/systemd/network/`.

Comment: For me, it was somehow caused by an existing VPN-connection that I had opened when started k3d. Once I stopped the VPN and re-stared the cluster, it worked.

Comment: I got the same issue when using pi-hole dns.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with k3s not being able to pull images and solved it by updating my `/etc/resolv.conf` to be symlinked from `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` on the host machine with

```
ln -sf /etc/resolv.conf /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

Comment: In my case both are the same.

Comment: @Robert Do you mean they have the same contents or they are already symlinked?